# PHP,MYSQL,ANDROID : Find similar/same questions asked already

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am creating a database which will have collection of questions and I would like to know if similar/same question has already been asked before.How can I do it? I am using php/mysql and making calls via Android.It cannot be fulltext match as few words may be added or removed but the gist of the question might be the same or the question might have the same answer. How can I proceed from here .Sorry I am a noob in this topic.I really appreciate any help.Thanks in advance

Eg: Who won the world-cup is very general but Who won the football world-cup is different from Who won the cricket world-cup .

Also:Who won the football world-cup in "YEAR"  is different but similar to Q starting with the "Year" +Who won the football  world-cup.

Also tried implementing lucene with android.But I am not sure if I am doing it right as it keeps crashing.

Comment: @Naufal not fulltext match like -(login/password) but the nlp/gist of question .

Comment: use "tags" in questions, make another table for tags and get tag id from here and associate it  with your questions, than get questions have same tags :)

Comment: Sounds like a great business plan. What code problems do you have?

Comment: @ShailendraSharma tags is already inbuilt but that does not solve the problem of matching questions as you need nlp to find the difference .I have used used lucene/solr on my localhost but I dont know how to make it live or host on cpanel on shared domain/webshosting .Btw Solr generates clusters/tags  if you have asked for it .But I am looking for something simpler to implement .Also I dont know how to put solr on my localhost(mamp/wamp) to live.

Comment: @tadman Thanks.Yes its something Stackoverflow uses but I am unable to implement it live on the php/mysql/android yet.But I really hope to do it .Also heard about carrot/redis but dont know how to implement it on my existing database and on existing structure .Also as you need nlp to find the difference .I have used used lucene/solr on my localhost but I dont know how to make it live or host on cpanel on shared domain/webshosting .Btw Solr generates clusters/tags if you have asked for it.But I am looking for something simpler to implement.

Comment: @tadman Also I dont know how to put solr on my localhost(mamp/wamp) to live.

Comment: Here is answer of your last question : 
Open **style.css** and go to line number **1350** then remove `background:none repeat scroll 0% 0% rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)`.

That's it.You are done.

**NOTE** : I would recommend to make it comment(like this/* */) instead of deleting so that if you want to use in future, you can use it easily.